# C# compare lists in a resource efficient way

Tags: c#, list, linq

this code works if string in list2 matches string in list1 and it is time efficient when it comes to larger lists

```
var firstNotSecond = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

however I'm trying to tweak it so that it would work if string in list2 contains a string in list1. So say if:

--list2 strings:

```
"john,sally,michael"
"tim,sally,andrew"
"stuart,bill,tom"
```

--list1 strings:

```
"sally"
"joe"
```

--final list would contain only last string from list2 as first two `.Contains`

```
"stuart,bill,tom"
```

I'm looking for the most time/resources efficient way to do this - the straight forward implementation with essentially two nested loops (with or without LINQ) is O(len(list1) * len(list2) ) - ideally I'd like same O(max(len(list1), len(list2))) as with `.Except`, but anything better than essentially n^2 is welcome.

Comment: Most efficient would probably be a linked list paired with a dictionary - I'd split the strings on comma and load a dictionary with the split keys, each pointing to the list node of the csv data. After the linked list is indexed thus, enumerate list two and remove the nodes from the linked list via the dictionary. If you're doing it with a normal list perhaps set the index location null then pass over the list again collecting only non nulls. If using a dictionary only, index the split array instead of the csv and upon first visit remove all keys from the dict based on the array

Comment: Or you can use HashSet

Comment: @OptionalOption can you please explain how you suggest to "use HashSet" for `.Contains`? It's obvious for equality, but the question is in part if it is possible to apply similar optimization to `.Contains` (I don't think so, but you seem to have an idea)

Comment: Ps time and resource efficient are usually exclusive - you can do nested loops and burn cpu time yet use little extra memory, you can hash up a dictionary index and really shorten the time but you need to store the index

Comment: Essentially every string must be compared in order to complete this, there is really no way to avoid O(nm) without over-engineering the solution.

Comment: @Travis There are data structure you can use that avoid that which every CS undergrad will have implemented at least once. Whether that's overengineered or not really depends on the use case and how big those lists and strings are.

Comment: the hash set solution looks like: load list 2(single names) into a hashset . For each element in list one (CSV names) split the string on comma and then for each entry in the split array ask if the hash set contains the name. If it does discard the entire list one entry. Linq's except method will use a some kind of hashed lookup internally too

Comment: @Voo - By all means, show us your data structure.

Comment: @Travis Build a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the strings in list 2 to enable more efficient comparisons

Comment: @Voo - The same link I shared earlier, very nice. I thought you were going to actually implement it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Your edit changed the question...the OP did not show they had *any* solution (not even a "straight forward implementation") to use `Contains`. You've imposed a constraint that wasn't there before by saying it had to be faster than `O(nm)`.

Comment: @RufusL I know... otherwise the question looked … less then good. "Give me any code" does look non-professional/non-enthusiast, so while I agree that edit is borderline questionable... there were no undeleted answers when I started the edit so looked fair game to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a two liner, along the lines of what Optional Option was thinking:

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>(list1);
var reducedList2 = list2.Where(s => s.Split(',').All(e => !hash.Contains(e))).ToList();
```

- Put sally and joe in the lookup
- Enumerate the list of csv strings, splitting them and rejecting them if any element in the csv is in the lookup (implemented here as "accept them if all elements are not in the lookup")

Few unavoidable(unless you want to change your data storage) nasties though, I think. If you don't truly need a List out at the end and could work with an enumerable, remove the ToList to avoid an expensive copy operation

It could be a lot better by being a linked list of node that have string arrays instead of a list of strings that are csv- no splitting and efficient removal of nodes. Internally there will be a lot of list resizing and data shuffling with your current storage solution

Answer (score 2):

You can find the items in `list1` `Where` `All` of the items in `list2` are not contained by the `list1` item using `System.Linq` extension methods:

```
var final = list1.Where(l1 => list2.All(l2 => !l1.Contains(l2))).ToList();
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive comparison, you can use the `IndexOf` method, along with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` (which returns `-1` if the item is not found):

```
var final = list1.Where(l1 => list2.All(l2 =>
    l1.IndexOf(l2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `l2` and convert it to a `HashSets`, so the `.Contains` will have complexity `O(1)`, and the whole algorithm will just have `O(n)`

```
public static List<string> ListExcept(this List<string> l1, List<string> l2)
{
    IEnumerable<HashSet<string>> listOfHashes = l1.Select(x => x.Split(',').ToHashSet());
    IEnumerable<HashSet<string>> finalLists = listOfHashes.Where(hash => l2.All(x => !hash.Contains(x)));
    IEnumerable<string> joined = finalLists.Select(x => x.Aggregate("", (s, s1) => s + s1 + ",")[..^1]);

    return joined.ToList();
}
```

Obviously you can join the calls, I split them and specified the types explicitly to make it clearer.

And then you can just call it as:

```
l2.ListExcept(l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The process essentially has to be O(nm) as each item has to be compared to the others. There is a way to build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and traverse if you really need to be efficient for extremely larger string sets.

Without building a trie, you can use a more simpler dictionary for lookups.

This will cut down a little on the process in a simpler approach by using O(1) to lookup matches, making this more of O(list2.length*list1.length) instead of having to compare each value. This will only improve performance for situations where the lists are longer and the O(1) lookup helps.

```
var list2Dict= list2.Select(l => l.ToDictionary( k => k, v => 0) ).ToList();
var result = list2.Where((_,i) => !list1.Any(l => list2Dict[i].ContainsKey(l))).ToList();
```

See it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/19gOCZ